# Issues with regular expression rejecting string

Tags: c, regex

```
regex_t regex;
int reti;
char msgbuf[100];

/* Compile regular expression, if two vowels it should be ok */
reti = regcomp(&regex, "[aoueiy].{2}", 0);
if (reti){
   fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
   exit(1);
}

/* Execute regular expression */
reti = regexec(&regex, "ao", 0, NULL, 0);
if (!reti) {
   puts("Match");
}
else if (reti == REG_NOMATCH) {
   puts("No match");
}
```

I am trying to write an expression that is supposed to accept an string that contains at least two vowels. Here is my code so far, the string ao gives me "No match". I am new to regex and I find the manual hard to use. Very thankful for any help or tips.

Comment: Pro tip: don't refer to the manual, yet. Check out https://regex101.com/ for the quick-n-dirty

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: Regex101 does not include Posix Basic Regular Expressions and consulting the manpage is a good way to learn that you need to provide `REG_EXTENDED` as a flag argument to `regcomp` if you want to avoid excessive use of backslashes.

Comment: @mattssoncode: The C regex library facilities support the obsolete "Basic Regular Expression" (BRE) syntax by default, as well as the more familiar "Extended Regular Expression" (ERE) syntax, which is probably what you want. To use ERE syntax, you must supply `REG_EXTENDED` in the flags when you call `regcomp`. (For BRE, you would need to put backslashes before the `{` and `}`, which in turn have to be doubled because in a C string a backslash is also an escape character. It's not worth the trouble to avoid a flag argument.)

Comment: @rici The faster that you arrive at the conclusion `#include <pcre2.h>`, the better.

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression matches a vowel followed by 2 other characters. `[aoueiy]` matches a vowel, `.` matches any characters, and adding `{2}` after it makes it match two characters. `ao` only has 1 character after the vowel, so it doesn't match.

The correct regexp is `[aoueiy].*[aoueiy]`. This matches two vowels with any number of characters (including 0) between them.

Comment: I tried his code and `[aoueiy]{2}` do not match it either. Any idea why? It should match "ao".

Comment: As mentioned in a comment above, you need to use extended regular expression to be able to use `{2}`

Comment: Ahh. Thanks for the info.